# How to evenly distribute an array with Scatterv

Tags: c++, arrays, c, mpi

My program is meant to take an array size and the elements of that particular array from the user.
However, I want the program to be able to distribute the array elements evenly for any number of processors used.

I think the problem is on the displs array, but even after countless try-outs, I don't seem to be reaching any logical conclusion.

Let's say I enter a sequence of 7 numbers -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
I will have an output as such:

```
processor 0
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
processor 1
arr[0] = 4
arr[1] = 5
processor 2
arr[0] = 7
arr[1] = 32767
```

The code is the following:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int myrank, wsize;
    int i,N;
    int *arr,*displs, *arr_r, *sendcount;
    int sum1=0;
    int portion,remainder,x,y;
    int root;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                  
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &wsize); 

    if(myrank == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter number N of integers\n");
        scanf("%d", &N); 

        arr = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        {
            printf("Enter number %d\n", i+1); 
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    portion = N / wsize;
    remainder = N % wsize;
    x = portion;
    y = portion +1;
    displs = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    sendcount = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(myrank < remainder)
        {
            sendcount[i] = portion + (remainder);
            displs[i] = (portion + (remainder)) * i;
        }
        else if(remainder == 0)
        {
            sendcount[i] = portion;
            displs[i] = portion *i;
        }
        else
        {
            sendcount[i] = portion;
            displs[i] = portion * i;
        }
        
    }

    arr_r = (int*)malloc(N *sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatterv(arr, sendcount, displs, MPI_INT, arr_r, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if(myrank < remainder)
    {
        printf("process %d \n",myrank);
        for(i = 0; i < portion + 1; i++)
        {
            printf("Arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr_r[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(remainder == 0)
    {
        printf("process %d \n",myrank);
        for(i = 0; i < portion; i++)
        {
            printf("Arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr_r[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("process %d \n",myrank);
        for(i = 0; i < portion; i++)
        {
            printf("Arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr_r[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the error is with the receive count (`N`).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you for answering. Could you please it point out a little bit more thoroughly?

Comment: yes I could, but believe me, that would not do you any favor in the long run. I just spotted an other issue: `displs` and `sendcounts` should **not** be arrays of `N` elements.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet that's what I am wondering, how should I form the displs one? Because I've done lots of try-outs for it, and I cannot get what needs to be done. I seem to be getting the point of these two arrays but I cannot get them to work, no matter what I change

Comment: the MPI standard or even `man MPI_Scatterv` can teach you the correct size of these arrays, and also the "relation" between the `sendcounts` and `recvcount` arguments.